# Boost Libraries and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, visual-studio-2013

I have installed boost using MSVC toolset through command-line(command prompt).

Now, I want to know which directories should I include in my project properties.

Since when I add the following line to my project:

```
#include <filesystem\fstream.hpp>
```

It throws the following error:

```
1>c:\boost\boost_1_56_0\boost\filesystem\fstream.hpp(15): fatal error C1083: 
Cannot open include file: 'boost/config.hpp': No such file or directory
```

I have added the followings to my project properties directories for libraries:

```
C:\boost\boost_1_56_0\boost
C:\boost\boost_1_56_0\stage\lib
```

This is where I have added the above paths:

```
(Project->Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't add the `boost` subdirectory to the search path; add the parent

```
C:\boost\boost_1_56_0
```

and specify the `boost` directory when you include the headers

```
#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>   // Better to use / not \ for portability
```

The Boost headers include each other like that (with `boost/` in the path), so now they can also be found.